# How to make a image inside of a button clickable

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm struggelig to figure out how I can make the image in the code under clickable. As of now only the button is clickable. Can i for instance give a value and onClick to the img-tag itself?

```
<button value="name" onClick={this.props.namechange}>
     <img id="pic" src={picture}></img>
</button>
```

Comment: Use button with attribute background for image with url `background: url([url]);`

Comment: When you click the button the action of click is effect the img "onClick" event and then the buttons "onClick"

Comment: @MichaelDurrant in the css file?

Comment: The `onClick` is bind to children of button as well. You can use `event.target.tagName` to determine what was clicked. Here is an example https://codepen.io/sanamumtaz/pen/bGWpRrE

Comment: @name yes in the css file though it will feel a bit odd.  Example `.button {background: url('/image/btn.png') no-repeat;}`

Comment: Also consider if you will want to use different images for different screen sizes, i.e. responsive views.  This may be one reason why having it in the css file is a good thing because that is where the responsive css is

Comment: Thank you so much, i solved it a while ago, but forgot to say that I did